# How to implement fling feature on an ImageView with Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe

I have an  `UIImageView` and I want to implement fling feature, when users flings on the screen the page can go up or down quickly.

Now my thinks is add two `UISwipeGesturesRecognizers`, but I don't know how to do next, should I use an animation to do this, and how to calculate the animation distance and time?

Also I find other answers said no need gesture recognizer can use scroll view, I am totally confused, are there any sample I can learn?

Comment: Are you looking for something like that : https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel ?

Comment: I am sorry no, I want to fling up and down.

Comment: You can fling up and down also using this

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that :

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];

NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"img1.png", @"img2.png", @"img3.png", nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++)
{
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * scrollView.frame.size.width;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
  [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height*[imagesArray count])];
```

Comment: I have some questions about above code, 1 where should I add these code, using a method or class? and what does the imagesArray used for, I don't need this array.